# How to avoid typedef redundancy in two different header files?

Tags: c++, c++11, typedef

I am trying to understand and then use the code written by someone else, but since I have little experience with `typedef`, I get confused at some point.

There are two different header files, one inheriting the other, and the same typedef is declared on both files.

Why does that redundancy occur, and how to avoid it?

**header_one.h:**

```
#include "header_two.h"
....

typedef std::map<std::string, StructName> RedundantTypedef;
....

class HeaderOneClass....
```

**header_two.h:**

```
....
struct StructName...
class HeaderTwoClass
{
public:
typedef std::map<std::string, StructName> RedundantTypedef;

std::map<std::string, StructName> getTypedefedDataStructure()
...
```

There are two basic issues which I don't understand here:

1. When I use the `RedundantTypedef` for the return type of `getTypedefedDataStructure()`, I get a compiler error: ‘RedundantTypedef’ does not name a type. This problem can be solved by using correctly the `::` scope resolution. And I understand that part.
2. When I move `typedef std::map<std::string, StructName> RedundantTypedef;` outside the `HeaderTwoClass` so I don't have to use the same `typedef` in `header_one.h` I again get an error. Error: ‘RedundantTypedef’ was not declared in this scope

What should be the correct arrangement of `typedefs` so I get no errors, and be able to use it as a return type for the `getTypedefedDataStructure()`

**SOLUTION:**

I found out why did the error to case 1 appeared. I was moving the `typedef std::map<std::string, StructName> RedundantTypedef;` above the `struct` declaration, and since this `typedef` contains `struuct StructName` within itself, the compiler would report error.

Thanks for the help to everyone. Should I keep the question, or should I delete it?

Comment: .. please quote concrete error messages as well

Comment: ... and make it a real [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please, the way the code sample is presented is pretty useless.

Comment: Do you use proper scope-resolution with `::`?

Comment: @Deduplicator yes, after using the scope-resolution everything is OK. But I am wondering why there are problems when keeping the `typedef` outside of the class

Comment: Because there were two definitions for the same name in the same compilation-unit?

Comment: BTW: Please don't self-answer in the question. Use an actual *answer* instead. (And remember that comments are temporary when you do.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to avoid conflicting names is by creating namespaces within the scope of the header page. Here is an example of a grocery store database I had to create for a final.

// File: store.h
// stores the items bought

```
#ifndef STOREITEM_H
#define STOREITEM_H

#include "getItem.h"

namespace groceryStore
{
class StoreItem
{
    public:
        StoreItem();
        StoreItem(Buying product, int quantity);
        Buying getId() const;
        int getQuantity() const;
        double getTotal() const;
        void increaseQuantity();
        bool operator == (StoreItem & o);
    private:
        int quantity;
        Buying product;
    };
}

#endif
```

I had 5 classes using a dArray which shops stores, does computation, gets, stores etc. Each.h file or class file has its own namespace and is accessed through the :: operator such as

```
// PRE: Must be called
// POST: Will return the id
groceryStore::Buying groceryStore::StoreItem::getId() const
{
    return product; // change to id
}
```

Above is a function for getting the product ID. With having each class have its own namespace I could have multiple getID() functions throughout the program which get their specific private data in the class. All I would have to change is the namespace which is groceryStore to the according class's namespace.

Using namespaces is highly necessary as a large program is split into teams and within these teams there are generic names such as "data","file", or non unique names that will conflict with each other. By using namespaces it prevents conflicts which makes life very simple.